# @NonNull not throwing compile error

Tags: java, annotations

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull;

  public class NullAnnotationTest {

        public void meth1(@NonNull String in) {
            System.out.println(in.length());
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            NullAnnotationTest test = new NullAnnotationTest();

            test.meth1(null);
        }
    }
```

If we have @NonNull annotation, i thought we will get compile time error if we call meth1 with a null argument. But i am not seeing any sort of errors or warning in the above program. Can some correct me?

Comment: In IntelliJ you don't get a compile error, only an editor warning.  Perhaps eclipse is smarter in this way??

Answer (score 1):

By default this feature i.e. `Enable annotation based null analysis` is DISABLE in eclipse.

Please enable this.  Go to `Window=>Preferences => Java=> Compiler => Error/Warning`. Enable the setting as shown in [image]

Once you have this setting enable, you will get `Null type mismatch: required '@NonNull String' but the provided value is null` compile time error.

Comment: I couldn't find this setting or an equivalent in IntelliJ Ultimate 2022.2.3. Does anyone know how to configure this? I find it a bit silly that I can put `@Nonnull` on a method parameter and then pass `null` to it explicitly and not get a compile-time error or IDE error.